# Best way to calculate and append the next unique number to some text in a treeview

Tags: javascript, treeview

I have Implemented a treeview that allows a user to drag and drop a node from one tree to another. The user can also reorder the node they just dropped to some other location in the tree as well as duplicate and remove existing nodes.

What I want to do next is so that every time a node is `added` or `duplicated`, it adds an incremented number to the end of the text if the text with that number doesn't exists.

Take this treeview for example.

```
Hello
  Hello (2)
    World (2)
  World
  Test
```

If I were to add a child node containing the text `World` to the node with the text `Test`, this is how the treeview should look like then.

```
Hello
  Hello (2)
    World (2)
  World
  Test
    World (3)
```

If I were to remove the node containing the text `World`, and add a node containing the text `World`. The treeview should look like this.

```
Hello
  Hello (2)
    World (2)
  Test
    World (3)
  World
```

Note that it didn't add an incremented number because it found that the text `World` didn't exist.

Right now I simply have an object containing the text as its key and storing the number of times it has encounter that text. Every time a node is added or duplicated, it increments the number of times it has seen that text.

The harder part is that when a node gets removed and the user adds a node with the same text, I need to somehow calculate which nodes got removed, update the dictionary appropriately and add the next unique number to each node.

**Note** - Only a single node can be added at a time but when it comes to duplicating or removing a node, not only is the node in question duplicated or removed but also its children. So you can imagine that when a node gets duplicated and the node has children, the algorithm that calculate the next unique number has to run not only for the node but also its children.

My question is, what data structure or technique can I employ to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I like this question. I’ll try to come back with code samples when I’m not on mobile.

---

You could go crazy with data structures trying to pre-compute the numeric value that should be assigned to the next inserted node, but like you pointed out, you’d have to remember to update when items were removed.

The DOM is already a tree. You have access to a node’s parent and children through [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) and [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) respectively.

I suspect that, for most cases, recursively searching the tree for the lowest number you can append will be faster than maintaining a list. The logic could be something like this:

```
given a node, some target text, and the current number

if the node contains the target text,
and the node contains the current number (or no number if the current number is 0),
increment the number

if the node has children,
for each child,
recurse using the child node, search text, and current number

return the current number
```

---

Passing in the `root` node, the search text, and `0` would recursively search the tree and return the lowest number still available.

If the number returned was `0` then either no matching nodes were found or all the matching nodes had a number (the original node with no number was deleted) and we are safe to insert a numberless node.

If a number greater than `0` was returned, then we are guaranteed that it is the lowest number we can use since, if it already existed in a matching node, it would have been incremented.

This approach also has the advantage of eliminating the work required when removing a node. Even if gaps are left in the numbers used for each match, the recursive function above will find the lowest gap and plug it. Once the gap is filled, it will increment to the next available gap or back to a number larger than all the numbers currently in use.

---

The last case is when a node is copied. What I would do is use another recursive function to incrementally clone the copied tree into the destination node’s children. Each node that was added would use the same `addNode` function used to insert a new node, and would therefore use the same recursive function above to assign a number.

The assumption this approach makes is that we are okay to number cloned nodes in the order in which we encounter them. If this is not acceptable and they must stay in the order in which the source subtree’s nodes were numbered, you have some additional work to do before insertion.

Comment: Your algorithm makes sense to me and looks sound. I just want to know your reason(s) for believing that searching in the tree for the lowest number for most cases would be faster than maintaining a list? Assuming of course that the tree gets bigger as the user adds new nodes and/or duplicate existing nodes.

Comment: Actually there is a fault in your logic I believe. You are assuming that we will find the current number before current number + 1, current number + 2 etc. In my first example, if you were to do a depth first traversal for the text world, you would first find world (2) before world. Doing breadth first traversal wouldn't help either since users can move the node to a new location.

Comment: Good catch. I am playing with the idea of setting [`data-`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) attributes on nodes for the `word` and the `instance` which would allow the use of `querySelectorAll('.node[data-word="search term"]')` to help calculate the lowest available instance number using the DOM's native tree traversal.

Comment: I was able to come with some solution to this problem. I'll post it as answer.

Comment: Posted an updated version of my solution. Check it out when you can.

Comment: Just so you and everyone else is aware, this problem, at the very least the part of finding the next unique number, can be boiled down to this leet code problem(https://leetcode.com/problems/first-missing-positive/). Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution that I was able to come up with. The solution has as its time complexity O(N) and space complexity O(1) (Not sure about the latter)

First I created a number array containing all the counts found so far.

`const counts: number[] = [];`

First, we need a recursive function that accepts as a callback the node that it has currently traverse. In that callback, we will search for the target text and if it is found, we will parse the text, calculate the sorted index using binary search and then push the value at that specific index.

```js
// Assumes that there are only one set of parenthesis. Adjust this function for
// your use case.
const extractNumberFromParenthesis = (text: string): number => {
   const start = text.indexOf('(');
   const end = text.indexOf(')');
   const number = text.substr(start + 1, end - start - 1);
   // The value 1 in this case represents the target text with no parenthesis
   return number ? parseInt(number) : 1;
}

const getSortedIndex = (value: number): number => {
  let low = 0;
  let high = counts.length;

  while (low < high) {
    // Prevent overflow and use bitwise operator for small performance gains.
    const mid = low + ((high - low) >> 1);

    if (counts[mid] < value) {
       low = mid + 1;
    } else {
       high = mid;
     }
  }

  return low;
};

// Recurse through the whole tree starting from the root node.
this._tree.recurseDown((node) => {
   if (!node.text.includes(text)) {
      return;
   }

   const count = extractCountFromParenthesis(node.text);
   const index = getSortedIndex(count);
   counts.splice(index, 0, count);
 });
```

Finally we can calculate the next unique number by searching for the first occurrence where `counts[i] !== i + 1`

```js
const getNextUniqueCount = () => {
  let nextUniqueCount = 0;

  while (
   nextUniqueCount < counts.length &&
   counts[nextUniqueCount] === nextUniqueCount + 1
  ) {
     nextUniqueCount += 1;
  }

  return nextUniqueCount;
};
```

Here is the whole code for reference.

```js
getTextWithNextUniqueCount(text: string): string {
    const counts: number[] = [];

    const extractCountFromParenthesis = (text: string): number => {
      const start = text.indexOf("(");
      const end = text.indexOf(")");
      const count = text.substr(start + 1, end - start - 1);
      return count ? parseInt(count) : 1;
    };

    const getSortedIndex = (value: number): number => {
      let low = 0;
      let high = counts.length;

      while (low < high) {
        const mid = low + ((high - low) >> 1);

        if (counts[mid] < value) {
          low = mid + 1;
        } else {
          high = mid;
        }
      }

      return low;
    };

    this._tree.recurseDown((node) => {
      if (!node.text.includes(text)) {
        return;
      }

      const count = extractCountFromParenthesis(node.text);
      const index = getSortedIndex(count);
      counts.splice(index, 0, count);
    });

    const getNextUniqueCount = (): number => {
      let nextUniqueCount = 0;

      while (
        nextUniqueCount < counts.length &&
        counts[nextUniqueCount] === nextUniqueCount + 1
      ) {
        nextUniqueCount += 1;
      }

      return nextUniqueCount;
    };

    const addCountToText = (): string => {
      const count = getNextUniqueCount();
      return count > 0 ? `${text} (${count + 1})` : text;
    };

    return addCountToText();
  }
```

This entire code will run each time we add a new node or duplicate it. No need to call this function when the node is removed.